# Android: Clear and update webview on gesture works in emulator not on phone

Tags: java, android, webview, gesture

I have a webview whose content needs to be updated on left->right or back right->left gesture. This works perfectly fine in my emulator running ICS 4.0.3 but the same does not seem to work on my samsung galaxy nexus running ICS 4.0.2. I can see the gesture getting detected in the device but the content of webview never gets updated. Following is the code I am using to update the webview

```
webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("about:blank", newContent, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

I have tried debugging and the value of the variable newContent is what as expected by the webview does not reflect it.

**EDIT:**

```
webView.loadData(body, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

the above was what worked but the update of webview does not look smooth at all which I guess I have to work on. But weird `loadDataWithBaseURL` works on the emulator and not on the device.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("about:blank", newContent, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

and remove your `loadUrl` call, which seems unnecessary.

Make sure that you're updating your webView in the main UI thread.

You might want to look at the newContent and make sure that it is well-formed HTML.

I've used that call `loadDataWithBaseURL` in several projects and it will change the content of the webView.